# Can p7zip create smaller zip files than winzip?

Tags: zip, compression, 7z

7-Zip for Windows creates smaller zip archives than WinZip, so presumably P7zip can create smaller zip archives than Zip in Linux. So how do I create zip files using P7zip in Linux?

Comment: You're in linux  Historically P7Zip is better used as a GUI in linux than an actual tool.  As such, P7Zip uses the native tool's on linux to create an archive.  I urge you to read the [Tar Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), not a discussion forum. Please ask separate questions separately — since nobody's answered different parts yet (fortunately), I edited out your second question, you're welcome to post it separately.

Comment: @ECarterYoung P7zip doesn't call any external tool. I don't know where you get that it's a GUI: P7zip is a command line tool (there are third-party GUI frontends for it).

Answer (score 2):

Experimentally, `7z` does compress a little better than `zip`. I don't know how it compares with Winzip.

```
$ zip -q zip.zip /bin/{bash,cp,ls}
$ zip -q -9 zip9.zip /bin/{bash,cp,ls}
$ 7z a 7z.zip /bin/{bash,cp,ls} >/dev/null
$ 7z -mx=9 a 7z9.zip /bin/{bash,cp,ls} >/dev/null
$ du -ab *.zip | sort -n
550617  7z9.zip
559890  7z.zip
576161  zip9.zip
578382  zip.zip
```

The numeric option (`-9` for `zip`, `-mx=9` for `7z`) tells the tool to spend more time to achieve a better compression ratio (it's a scale from 0 to 9).

You'll get better compression by using 7z format instead of zip format. The downside is that you need P7zip for decompression, Winzip can't handle it.

```
$ 7z -mx=9 a 7z9.7z /bin/{bash,cp,ls} >/dev/null 
$ 7z a 7z.7z /bin/{bash,cp,ls} >/dev/null 
$ du -ab *.7z | sort -n
471964  7z9.7z
472415  7z.7z
```

Install P7zip from your distribution's packages; if you have some weirdly incomplete distribution that doesn't include it, get it from [upstream](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/). There are three executables (sometimes package separately): `7zr` only handles 7z archives, `7z` handles many common archive formats (including zip), and `7za` supports additional plugins (useful for rar, which requires non-free code that isn't linked into 7z itself). You can use the option `-m` to select the archive format, but usually this isn't required since the tool selects the format from the file name.